# Android Design Support Library More Than Backward Compatibility?

Tags: android, material-design

Is Android Design Support Library only for backward compatibility or does it have features that are worth using even if you are not interested in backward compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the features found specifically in the [Design Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) are found elsewhere (i.e., in the framework code, etc) so no, it is not only for backward compatibility.